# 3d matrix to 2d adjacency matrix or edgelist

Tags: python, r, networkx, igraph, adjacency-matrix

Consider a **3 x 3 x 3** cube where each of the 27 elements is connected to other elements along faces. A cube-shaped element has 6 sides, thus a maximum of 6 connections is possible per element (for example, the center-most element in a 3 x 3 x 3 cube is bounded by 6 elements, and has 6 connections).

Then, let `m1`, `m2`, and `m3` be the first, second, and third layers of the cube respectively. The name of each element is `xyz`, where `x`, `y`, `z` are the row number, column number, and layer number of the element. For example, the element `213` is in the second row, first column, and 3rd layer of the cube. This element is connected to 4 other elements: three are in its layer (`113, 313, 223`), and one is one layer above it (`212`).

```
x = 3 # nrow
y = 3 # ncol
z = 3 # nlay

# print each layer as a 2D matrix
for(k in 1:z){
  m = paste0(rep(1:x, each=x), rep(1:y, times = y), k)
  print(matrix(m, nrow=x, byrow=T))
}

     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "111" "121" "131"
[2,] "211" "221" "231"
[3,] "311" "321" "331"
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "112" "122" "132"
[2,] "212" "222" "232"
[3,] "312" "322" "332"
     [,1]  [,2]  [,3] 
[1,] "113" "123" "133"
[2,] "213" "223" "233"
[3,] "313" "323" "333"
```

#### Is there an out-of-the-box function in `igraph` or a related package for creating either an **adjacency matrix OR an edge list** for a network like this? I need a solution **that scales to any number of rows, columns, and layers**. Python solutions are welcome.

I manually created the 2D adjacency matrix, where the rows and columns are given by `c(m1, m2, m3)` below:

```
m1 = paste0(rep(1:x, each=x), rep(1:y, times = y), 1)
m2 = paste0(rep(1:x, each=x), rep(1:y, times = y), 2)
m3 = paste0(rep(1:x, each=x), rep(1:y, times = y), 3)
c(m1, m2, m3)
 [1] "111" "121" "131" "211" "221" "231" "311" "321" "331" "112" "122" "132" "212" "222" "232" "312" "322" "332"
[19] "113" "123" "133" "213" "223" "233" "313" "323" "333"
```

For this simple example the adjacency matrix is sparse, has 0's along the diagonal, and is symmetric. It looks like this:

[image]

And here's a `dput()` to C&P and validate with.

```
dput(temp)
structure(c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(27L, 
27L), .Dimnames = list(c("111", "121", "131", "211", "221", "231", 
"311", "321", "331", "112", "122", "132", "212", "222", "232", 
"312", "322", "332", "113", "123", "133", "213", "223", "233", 
"313", "323", "333"), c("111", "121", "131", "211", "221", "231", 
"311", "321", "331", "112", "122", "132", "212", "222", "232", 
"312", "322", "332", "113", "123", "133", "213", "223", "233", 
"313", "323", "333")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an edge when the Manhattan distance between the nodes is 1, so you can use `dist()` in R to create the adjacency matrix:

```
cube_mat = expand.grid(
    x = 1:3,
    y = 1:3,
    z = 1:3
)

m_dist = as.matrix(dist(cube_mat[, 1:3], method = "manhattan", diag = TRUE))
# Zero out any distances != 1
m_dist[m_dist != 1] = 0
rownames(m_dist) = paste0(cube_mat$x, cube_mat$y, cube_mat$z)
colnames(m_dist) = paste0(cube_mat$x, cube_mat$y, cube_mat$z)
# Plot of the adjacency matrix (looks reversed because 111 is in the bottom left):
image(m_dist)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just use a package funtion from `igraph`:

```
#adj <- my.adjacency.matrix
as_edgelist(graph.adjacency(adj))
```

In general you can use the functions in the igraph package to go between edgelists, adjacency matrices, and also produce graphs using `plot.igraph`. Here's the default cube:

```
plot.igraph(graph.adjacency(adj))
```

[image: default network plot]